# Guzzle - How to set json Header?

Tags: php, guzzle

It appear `Accept: application/json` has not been set for the request header. I am not getting json response.

```
$params = [
    'client_id'     => 'xxxx',
    'client_secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxx',
    'code'          => $request->get('code'),
    'state'         => $request->get('state'),
];

$client = new Client(['headers' => ['Accept: application/json']]);
$response = $client->post($tokenUrl, [
    'form_params' => $params,
]);

echo $response->getBody();
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should write the headers as an associative array, according to http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html.

So, try

```
$client = new Client(['headers' => ['Accept' => 'application/json']]);
```

Comment: Phew. Your answer saved me. Thanks !